cloudflare tunnel not routed properly
I am working on deploying cloudflare tunnel by terraform.
/module/tunnel/main.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    cloudflare = {
      source = "cloudflare/cloudflare"
    }
  }
}

resource "random_password" "tunnel_secret" {
  length = 64
}

resource "cloudflare_tunnel" "auto_tunnel" {
  account_id = var.cloudflare_account_id
  name       = "AKS Tunnel ${var.environment}"
  secret     = base64sha256(random_password.tunnel_secret.result)
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "cname" {
  zone_id = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  name    = var.prefix
  value   = cloudflare_tunnel.auto_tunnel.cname
  type    = "CNAME"
  proxied = true
}

resource "cloudflare_tunnel_config" "auto_tunnel" {
  tunnel_id  = cloudflare_tunnel.auto_tunnel.id
  account_id = var.cloudflare_account_id
  config {
    ingress_rule {
      hostname = cloudflare_record.cname.hostname
      path     = "/sample/*"
      service  = "http://10.1.2.7:80"
    }

    ingress_rule {
      hostname = cloudflare_record.cname.hostname
      path     = "/app/*"
      service  = "http://10.1.2.7:80"
    }

    ingress_rule {
      service = "http_status:404"
    }
  }
}

10.1.2.7 is private ip address of istio internal ingress gateway.
gateway.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: app-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: aks-istio-ingressgateway-internal
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: store-front
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /sample
    route:
    - destination:
        host: store-front
        port:
          number: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: web-service
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - app-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /app
    route:
    - destination:
        host: web-service
        port:
          number: 5001

When I try to access http://example.com/app or http://example.com/sample, my browser gives me 404 error.
Cloudflare log tells me the same thing.
isito's sidecars are injected properly.
Is there any cause?
k8s version is 1.30 and istio version is 1.22, both of which are latest.
k8s is applied by Azure Kubernetes Service.
